# store procedure not giving correct values

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I am trying to find the number of employees with a specific salary range using store procedure, I am getting results but they are not equal to the results of the simple query (second query below) which means that the store procedure is not working properly?

I was hoping if someone can help me with this.

-- ANSWER : NULL /there is no salary amount less than 38000, however with the store procedure I am getting 967330

Secondly, is there any other way to shorten the case when statements within the store procedure ? in the current version I have to add subquery each time.

database name: employees
column name: salary
employee_id = emp_no

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE SALARY_RANGE
(INOUT no_employees INT, IN salary INT)
BEGIN
CASE
WHEN (salary <= 38000) THEN (SELECT COUNT(emp_no) INTO no_employees 
                        FROM salaries 
                            WHERE salary <= 38000);
                            
WHEN (salary<= 68000) THEN (SELECT COUNT(emp_no) INTO no_employees 
                        FROM salaries
                            WHERE  salary <= 68000);
WHEN (salary <= 88000) THEN (SELECT COUNT(emp_no) INTO no_employees 
                        FROM salaries
                            WHERE  salary <= 88000);
WHEN (salary <= 100000) THEN (SELECT COUNT(emp_no) INTO no_employees 
                        FROM salaries
                            WHERE  salary <=  100000);  
ELSE (SELECT COUNT(emp_no) INTO no_employees 
FROM salaries WHERE salary > 100000);
END CASE;
END$$

CALL SALARY_RANGE(@finding_salary_range_count,'38000')$$
select @finding_salary_range_count;


-- to check the if the answer matched the above store procedure
select count(case when salary <= 88000 then emp_no else null end) as count_sal
from salaries;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would expect code like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SALARY_RANGE (
    OUT out_num_employees INT,
    IN in_salary INT
)
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(emp_no) INTO out_num_employees 
    FROM salaries 
    WHERE salary <= in_salary or in_salary IS NULL
END;
```

I don't see a need for multiple `SELECT` statements.